# Put an image behind the title in a WP, WooCommerce "shop" page

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, background-image

I am probably missing something simple but...

I have a website created with WordPress that has a WooCommerce shop on it.
I want to put an image behind the "Shop" text in the banner on the page.
Can't seem to find a way to do it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[Link to website page in question](https://malcolmwray.com/shop/)

Not editable with Elementor!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that, the simplest one would be to apply it using CSS

```
.woocommerce-shop .title-container-outer-wrap{
     background-image: url('YOUR_IMAGE_URL');
}
```

I have referred to the body class `.woocommerce-shop` so that it only applies to the shop page.

Another way would be to override the WooCommerce `archive-product` template.
For that, you need to copy the `woocommerce/templates/archive-products.php` file inside your child theme directory and make the desired changes.

https://woo.com/document/template-structure/
Follow this link for more details on template overriding.